# Disable layout width and height auto import feature and suggestion

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I disable Android Studio layout editor feature of auto import `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`?

I want, when I write some new component, it come with no attributes.

1. This is what comes automatically when writing new component.

[image: comes]

2. This is what I want

[image: want]

**I want this because-**

Yes all component must have both height and width, I always use my App Custom Styles for every component.

**For Example** every parent element has both height and width `match_parent`, so I just set my style `ViewParent` style for all parent element views. and I don't specify height and width everywhere. I use styles for better maintainability.

Comment: These attributes are mandatory. What would be the reason that you want them to be removed?

Comment: @GilGoldzweig The reason is that I always use my App styles for every component, like every parent element has both height and width `match_parent`, so I just set `ViewParent` style to the all parent element. I use styles for better maintainability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Android Studio preferences `-> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys`.

Then uncheck `Insert required attributes on tag completion`.

[image]